# Why is my eclipse Workspace empty?

Tags: android, eclipse

I use Eclipse to implement android application and the workspace is empty. I can't find any of my projects and if I try to load one, it shows error as invalid description. All my projects are in the proper workspace location but still why cant I see them?

Comment: Did you change the root directory of your workspace? Are you sure you are not in a different one? Try searching the files in your computer. If the files are not there, eclipse won't show them. Or, at least it will notify that a change has been made.

Comment: All my files are there, I didnt change anything. I just opened eclipse like any other time and nothing was there.

Comment: What if you try to once again import your projects?

Comment: I get a description error

Comment: The error wont solve my problem. I need to find a way to get my projects visible. The error is because the project is already in my workspace

Comment: You should have shown something.Like a photo of your empty workspace.

Comment: Can you see the 'package explorer'or package explorer itself is hidden? I think your package explorer is accidentally closed. Open it in Window > Show view

Comment: Try to recreate your workspace: (1) exit Eclipse, (2) rename the workspace to something else, (3) create a new workspace with the name and location of the old one and  (4) import all existing projects with "copy projects into workspace" selected.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the workspace folder and delete the ".metadata" folder(which might be hidden).
2. Open eclipse and import the project again.

Answer (score 0):

When I'm using eclipse and i put a project into a workspace and then try to import this project in eclipse I get an error because the project is already in this workspace, even when it's not seen in eclipse.

So, clean your workspace and try to import the project from a different folder.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a severe bug in Eclipse. See the ticket:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=462571

The workbench.xmi under the following path could have problem, so that the prolog parser could not parse the projects tree:

***your_work_space\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.e4.workbench***